# How to show Document library documents based on User

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document

I need to show documents in document library based on a user.

For example, I have one list in which I have some Projects for the user. Based on the Projects he has I need to show the documents in document library based on Project folders.

For example I have folders `Abc, xyz, sss`. The user has only `abc ,sss Projects` so I need to show only those folders.

Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: And how do you decide that the user has only access to abc, sss projects? Where are the permissions stored?

Comment: i am inheriting  Permissions by group and user access  to Projects are stored in list.In document library i have folders with Project Names.so My requirement is to show document library folders which he had access

Comment: I don't think anything OOB can be done here, if each project had a separate web than you could be able to play with web permissions.. but storing in list will require some development efforts

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include structure of the list and structure of the document library?

Comment: Currently my list have 7 to 8 users like user 1 xyz, abc Projects  user 2 xyz, efg Projects and so on And document library have folders with Project names like xyz, abc, efg,... so i need to show folders in document library based on that Projects assigned to users.I am trying hard to find a way for achieving this functionality.